# Create a free running timer in real time linux

Tags: c, linux, timer, timestamp, rtos

I am studying real time linux and want to create a free running timer. But I am not able to find information regarding the real time linux. Could someone suggests me some document or could someone tell me how to create a free running high precision timer ??

Achievement : After creating a free running timer, So that I can get the time stamp value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The entire point of using real-time Linux is that it *is Linux* - all the existing Linux and POSIX services are available, and you should avoid using proprietary non-POSIX OS services if portability is an issue - otherwise you may as well be using a true RTOS.

The standard function [`clock()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/clock) has a `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` of 1000000 (i.e. microseconds) on POSIX.  The actual granularity is implementation dependent however.  You can check this for your system with:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    clock_t t0 = clock() ;
    clock_t t1 = t0 ;
    while( t0 == t1 )
    {
        t1 = clock() ;
    }

    printf( "Clock granularity = %lf seconds\n", (double)(t1 - t0)/(double)(CLOCKS_PER_SEC) ) ;

    return 0 ;
}
```

On ideone.com, this gave the following result:

```
Clock granularity = 0.010000 seconds
```

i.e. 10ms.

If that is not sufficient, a number of clock sources are defined for use with [`clock_gettime()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/clock_gettime) and the resolution of each can be determined by `clock_getres()`.  The clock ID `CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID` is likely to be appropriate.  Note that resolution and granularity are not the same here either.  I performed the following test on ideone.com:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    struct timespec t0 ;
    struct timespec t1 ;
    clock_gettime( CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, &t0) ;
    t1 = t0 ;
    while( t0.tv_nsec == t1.tv_nsec )
    {
        clock_gettime( CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, &t1) ;
    }

    printf( "Clock granularity = %lf seconds\n", (double)(t1.tv_nsec - t0.tv_nsec)/1e9 ) ;

    struct timespec res ;
    clock_getres( CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, &res ) ;
    printf( "CPUTIME resolution = %.15lf seconds\n", e, (double)(res.tv_nsec)/1e9) ;


    return 0 ;
}
```

With results:

```
Clock granularity = 0.000001 seconds
CPUTIME resolution = 0.000000001000000 seconds
```

So the granularity is 1 microsecond.